# Problema com lock no liquibase + SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, liquibase

Bom dia,

Criei uma aplicação Spring Boot e através do properties habilitei o liquibase para verificar se é necessário efetuar algum upgrade na estrutura do banco de dados.

O problema é que o primeiro passo executado é verificar se há algum lock no banco de dados para poder efetuar as mudanças. Se não tiver ele trava o banco de dados para verificar se é necessário aplicar alguma atualização. Aconteceu que algumas vezes a aplicação caiu antes de liberar o lock e eu tive que manualmente remover esse lock.

Quando a aplicação encontrar um lock, há alguma forma de ela ignorar a execução do liquibase ao invés de não conseguir subir? Ou simplesmente remover o lock após algumas tentativas?

Aproveitando a pergunta, utilizar o liquibase para atualizar automaticamente o banco de dados é uma boa ou má prática para se colocar em produção?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiramente, **não é possível** remover automaticamente o lock.

O lock do liquibase é um mecanismo criado justamente para evitar que duas atualizações de banco sejam realizadas ao mesmo tempo.

Forçar a remoção dessa flag durante uma execução poderia causar uma inconsistência, já que o liquibase em sí não sabe se existe alguma outra execução atualizando a base naquele momento (operações de reindexação de tabelas levam muito tempo dependendo do tamanho da tabela), ou, se ocorreu um erro e o lock ficou como uma sobra de execução. Nesse segundo caso você procedeu de forma correta, removendo o lock manualmente.

Sobre a sua outra pergunta, utilizar o termo boa prática ou má prática pode ser controverso, mas, não existe nenhum problema em utilizar isso em produção, no entanto, se você tem problemas com a instância que executa o script, isso pode (e vai) lhe causar vários problemas (o lock é um deles por exemplo).

É importante você ter um ambiente consistente antes de mais nada, com certeza seguir com a resolução do problema de terminação de sua instância durante o processo de execução seria a primeira coisa a se fazer.

Comment: Eu entendo porque existe o lock, é que nesse caso específico eu tenho certeza que essa á a única aplicação que mexe nesse banco. Seria possível então se ele não conseguir o lock ao menos a aplicação subir sem executar o Liquibase? Pois hoje, se ela tenta pegar o lock do banco e não consegue a aplicação não sobe.

Comment: Nativamente do liquibase não existe recurso para remover o lock, entretanto, você pode criar uma ferramenta que realize a checagem do registro de lock e remova manualmente antes de executar o seu step do liquibase. É importante sempre garantir que não existem duas execuções em paralelo de alguma forma.

Comment: Atualmente sua aplicação sobe e também roda o liquibase? Uma abordagem interessante seria separar essa responsabilidade em outro projeto que apenas execute o liquibase, dessa forma sua aplicação sempre iria subir utilizando a base, que no caso, foi gerenciada por um step anterior, em outro projeto

Comment: Eu estava utilizando o liquibase com Spring Boot devido a facilidade de implementação, mas estou pensando em alterar isso por causa desse problema da aplicação não subir caso tenha algum problema com o liquibase. Achei que poderia existir uma solução para isso. Obrigado. Dúvida respondida. Vou verificar se coloco o script do liquibase rodando no terraform da aplicação no lugar de subir com o spring boot.